# PHP combining counting files in a directory by type

Tags: php

The following recursively returns images and videos based on the given directory. A multitude of directories and files are returned for each user. What I would like to do is figure out a way to count the images and the videos returned from each directory and combine the results of all the directories returned for a user.

```
$results = [];
function getDirEnties($directory, &$results, $friend, $static_path) {
    $i = 0;      
    $entries = scandir($directory);
    foreach ($entries as $item) {
        if (!in_array($item, ['.', '..']) && substr($item, 0, 1) !== '.') {
            $path = $directory . '/' . $item;
            $rel_path = $static_path . '/' . $item;
            if (is_dir($path)) {
                getDirEnties($path, $results, $friend, $rel_path);
            } else {
                $i++;
                $pathInfo = pathinfo($path);
                $name = $pathInfo['filename'];
                $type = 'unknown';
                if (!empty($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                    $name .= "." . $pathInfo['extension'];
                    switch (strtolower($pathInfo['extension'])) {
                        case "gif":
                        case "jpg":
                        case "png":
                        case "jpeg":
                        case "bmp":
                        //etc..
                        $type = 'image';
                        break;
                        case "mp4":
                        $type = 'video';
                        break;
                    }
                }
                $tttt = filemtime($path);
                $data = [
                    'name' => $name,
                    'username' => $friend,
                    'path' => $rel_path,
                    'type' => $type,
                    'id' => $i,
                    'time' => date('F d Y h:i A', $tttt)
                ];
                $results[] = $data;
            }
        } 
    }
    return $data;
}
```

I am not entire sure how to do this but something like:

```
$imgcount = glob($directory.".{jpg,png,gif}", GLOB_BRACE);
$total_images = ($imgcount + $imgcount);

$vidcount = glob($directory.".{mp4}", GLOB_BRACE);
$total_videos = ($vidcount + $vidcount);
```

Keeping in mind I am combining dozens, hundreds and potentially even thousands of directories, how would I get the proper counts?

**UPDATE**

I need the function to exist outside of the main function as I am only call the listed function on a specific page where I am outputting. I want the count to exist on other pages where I am not recursively displaying results.

Comment: Since you iterate through all folders anyway there is no sense in additionally using `glob`. Just keep track in a variable defined outside the inner scope and hand that one over to your function `getDirEnties()` as an additional reference argument.

Comment: I thought about that, but I only iterate through them on a specific page, and I want to display the counts on a multitude of pages, so I am thinking a separate function would be the best way, jsut not entirely sure how to do it.

Comment: Ah, ok, that is something completely different! Why don't you say so in your question?

Comment: The issue with name pattern based type detection is that it only works for the typical file name extensions you have in mind when implementing stuff. File name extensions are really obsolete these days. So such a strategy may very well deliver a totally wrong result...

Comment: I updated the question, and in typical situations you wouldn't be wrong, but when I am naming what file types are allowed by both extension and mimetype elsewhere in the app, the recalling them assures me of exact extensions to be returned, so if someone tries to upload a php as a jpg, it will not be allowed by the app.

Comment: Hm, sure, possible, but _why_ would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use an associative array.

```
$i = 0;      
$filesCount = array();
$entries = scandir($directory);
```

then:

```
                 $ext = $pathInfo['extension'] ;
                if (!empty($ext)) {
                    if (!isset($filesCount[strtolower($ext)]) {
                        $filesCount[strtolower($ext)] = 0;                            
                    }
                    $filesCount[strtolower($ext)]++;
                    $name .= "." . $ext;
```

At the end:

```
$totalImages = $filesCount["jpg"] + $filesCount["gif"] + ...
```

Comment: If Im understanding what you are suggesting you are basically saying either use my existing function or recreate the same function, which will do the exact same thing of checking each and every file for its extension and then counting it. At that point, a second function wouldn't be needed, as this function already does what you are suggesting. Just output final $data['id'] from existing array by doing a while (!isset($data[id]) && (data[type]=='image')) {...

Comment: There are several ways of doing it, you can use the shell or list all the files into a string and use regular expressions. However I don't have php here so I'm limited to showing you how I would count the files by using an associative array. As for the update to your question you can design a class.